# authorization filter in layered architecture

Tags: authorization, domain-driven-design, acl, ddd-repositories

Having a logical layered architecture means I have a layer with the only concern of updating or fetching data for the higher layers. Some of the queries from the consuming application have to return only the entities that the current user controlling the application has access to. For instance in an application for a user to manage computers, searching computers by name should only return matching computers that the user has access to obviously. Is it ok to put this filter, restricting the query to the ones the caller has access to, in this bottom data access layer or does this information have to be injected or passed down from upper layers?

The thing that confuses me is that obviously fetching a lot of information just to throw it away later on its a waste of time but giving this layer this responsibility seems incorrect because I see it as a dumb IO layer (and this authorization like business logic that would prevent me from changing how it works in 1 place and it being transparent to all other components).

How is this type of scenario usually handled both in theory and in practice?

Answer (score 4):

In `DDD` there are many architectures. Some of them are said to be layered, some are not. In any case, there is a `layer` (or `slice` or `component` or whatever you want to call it) that contains only domain code; that domain layer has not dependency to other layers, contains only pure business logic. The first client of that layer is called `Application layer` that contains `Application services` that have , among other, the authorization responsibility; it checks if a user is permitted to execute some command (modify the state of the system) or query (view some data). Although it may seem that this `authorization` contain business logic, this logic is different from the `core business logic`.

So, about your example, the domain code should not check by itself if a user has access to some computers. The repository should expose a filter that the `Application services` could use to filter the computers the user has access to. It is OK to put this functionality inside the repository. In fact, in my opinion, the repository does not belong in the domain layer, not even the `repository interfaces`.

In `CQRS`, the command side of the domain layer does not contain any trace of repository/infrastructure code/interfaces, only pure domain logic. The **application service authorize the user**, loads the aggregate then call a method on it (here stays the domain code) then persist the aggregate.

On the query side there may be infrastructure code involved in the read-model, in order to keep even the domain layer thin. *Here reside the filters that can be used by the application services to filter the computers the user has access to*, but those filters are no pre-applied by the domain code, they are just exposed to `application services` use.

**So, the conclusion, is to not mix the authorization code with the domain/business logic code**.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this done in many different places. As with most programming problems the best solution depends on many things.

### At the DAL (Data Access Layer)

You would need to determine who the currently authenticated user is so you know which columns to select and/or which clauses to add to the database query. This could get messy really fast.

### When the data is being serialized

As the data is being serialized for the view. Depending on the features of your serialization library you can add your own custom code which is executed before, during (as it serializes each field) or after the serialization process. This allows you to decide on which fields should or should not be in the final serialized version of the data.

### Enforce certain filters on the query

If you follow Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) you would be familiar with a query bus. You create a query object, send it to the query bus, it finds a query handler for the query which executes the query and returns the data.

Taking your example where you only want the user to be able to search for computers which are related to him.

```
class FindAllComputersQuery
{
    private $filters = [];

    public function __construct(array $filters = [])
    {
        $this->filters = $filters;
    }

    public function getFilters() : array
    {
        return $this->filters;
    }
}
```

The query handler

```
public function handle(FindAllComputersQuery $query) : array
{
    $filters = $query->getFilters();

    // Generate basic SQL to get all computers
    // If the 'userId' filter exists then add
    // some JOINs or WHEREs to the query to
    // filter the result set down to a specific user
}
```

A query bus usually has middleware or something similar which will allow you to add some extra functionality to it like executing some code before or after a query executes. You can:

Create a `QueryAuthorization` middleware which executes before the query is executed by its handler. This `QueryAuthorization` middleware can have many `QueryAuthorizers` added to it.

Every time a query is sent into the query bus the `QueryAuthorization` middleware is executed (passing the query to it).

The `QueryAuthorization` middleware then iterates over all its `QueryAuthorizers`. If a `QueryAuthorizer` that supports the current query is found it calls the `authorize($query, User $user)` method.

```
interface QueryAuthorizer
{
    public function supports($query) : bool;

    public function authorize($query, User $user);
}

class EnsureUserSeesOwnComputersOnly implements QueryAuthorizer
{

    public function supports($query) : bool
    {
        return ($query instanceof FindAllComputersQuery);
    }

    public function authorize($query, User $user)
    {
        // If the user is an ADMIN don't enforce anything.
        if ($user->hasRole('ADMIN')) {
            return;
        }

        $filters = $query->getFilters();

        // Ensure the 'userId' filter is set and that its value
        // is equal to the ID of the currently authenticated user.
        // You don't want the user to be able to put in another users ID.
        if (!isset($filters['userId'] || $filters['userId'] !== $user->getId())
        {
            // Throw some authorization exception because the required
            // userId filter was not supply or it was supplied but the ID
            // is not the ID of the currently authenticated user.
        }
    }
```

With this approach you can have a HTTP endpoint which allows you to retrieve all computers `/computers` and add different filters by doing `/computers?userId=some-user-id`.

In the controller you simply extract the query string parameters from the request (the filters), create the query object and execute it using the query bus. The query buses `QueryAuthorization` middleware gets called which in turn calls the `EnsureUserSeesOwnComputersOnly` `QueryAuthorizer`.

Controller

```
$filters = // Get query string parameters from HTTP request
$query = new FindAllComputersQuery($filters);
$computers = $this->queryBus->execute($query);

// Serialize the computers and return a JSON response
```

The admin can send a request to `/computers` but a user must at the very least send a request to `/computers?userId=USERS_OWN_ID_HERE`.

With this approach the controller and the query handler stay light as they do not have to deal with cross cutting concerns such as authorization.

Using this approach you can very easily continue to add more and more `QueryAuthorizers` whenever you need them. A query can have any number of `QueryAuthorizer`s. You should give your `QueryAuthorizers` descriptive names so you instantly know at a glance what each one does.